# Swift pass block from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I have a method in Objective-C that takes a parameter and returns a result in a block. How do I return this result through a bridging header to a swift block? Note I have other non-block functions returning and this works fine.

Objective-C

```
   - (void)performMethod:(NSString*)myString
    {    
        [self.class
         doSomething:myString
         onSuccess:^(NSArray * results) {
           // Return results
         }
         onFailure:^(NSError * error) {
           // Return error
         }];
    }
```

Bridging header

```
?
```

Swift

```
class.performMethod(myString:String)->(results) in NSArray {

}
```

Comment: ... takes a parameter and returns a result in a block ... ??? your function doesn't return anything but void.

Comment: That was the question - how should the performMethod be structured so that I can return a result in a block to a swift method via a bridging header. The block I referenced is within onSuccess:

Comment: check again my 'notes'. you objectiv c function DOESN'T return any block. it returns void. what did you declare as a 'prototyp' of your swift code has nothing with your objective c code. do you ask how to 'translate' your objective code to swift?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a bridging header? Feel free to adjust the objective-c function so that the result in onSuccess or onFailure is returned through the performMethod method.

Comment: yes, i am. do you want to write some objective c function with the same signature as your swift code? or what do you want to do ? i am sorry, but you question is "I have a method in Objective-C that takes a parameter and returns a result in a block. How do I return this result through a bridging header to a swift block?" so the only answer is, that your function doesn't return anything, but void ....

Answer (score 0):

the trouble is that your Objective C function return void, not some block

how to deal with block in swift ? see the example below

```
// this block takes an Int as parameter and returns an Int
let myBlock: (Int)->Int = { i in
    return i
}
let i = myBlock(10)
print(i) // 10
// this block takes no parameters and return an empty Array<Int>
let myBlock2: ()->Array<Int> = { Void in
    return [Int]()
}
print(myBlock2.dynamicType) // () -> Array<Int>
let arr = myBlock2()
print(arr, arr.dynamicType) // [] Array<Int>
```

from what i can see in your code, you try to do something like

```
import Foundation

func bar(str: String, onSucces: ()-> NSArray, onError: ()->NSError) {
    // do something with str
    if str == "alfa" {
        // success
        let arr = onSucces()
        print(arr)
    } else {
        let err = onError()
        print(err)
    }
}

func foo(str: String) -> Void {
    bar(str, onSucces: { () -> NSArray in
        return NSArray(array: [str])
        }) { () -> NSError in
            return NSError(domain: "error", code: -1, userInfo: nil)
    }
}

foo("alfa")
/*
(
alfa
)
*/

foo("")
/*
Error Domain=error Code=-1 "(null)"
*/
```

Comment: dear down voter, please explain you decision, so i can fulfil your requirements next time. thank you in advance!